# How to check if record exist in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm thinking how can I check if I my record exists running raw SQL queries. I tried to use `is_null` function but it doesn't work for me. So when I try to select wrong values and hitting the submit button it return me  the 'Success' plain text in the browser.

```
public function readEmployeeRecords()
{
    $users = DB::select('select * from users where username = ?', [1]);

    if(is_null($users))
    {
        return ('Failed');  
    }
    else
    {
        return('Success');
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
<form class = "form-inline" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.accountSearch') }}">

<div class = "form-group">

    <input type = "text" name = "search" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Employee username">

</div>

<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Search</button>
<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

Comment: you could `var_dump($users)` to see what is returned and check against it.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using the ORM built it option like `first` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT EXISTS( your subquery )`:

```
public function readEmployeeRecords()
{
    $users = DB::select('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?)', [1]);

    if (!$users[0]) {
        return ('Failed');  
    }
    else {
        return('Success');
    }
}
```

My original answer was using `COUNT(*)`, which logically should have worked.  However, I suspect th0at one "record" was always being returned, regardless of the actual count.

Comment: It still print me the else condition bro.

Comment: @Francisunoxx Don't bro me if you don't know me :-)  ... working on an update for you now.

Comment: Appreciated your time. But still it returns me `Success`.

Comment: I believe the query I gave you will behave as expected.  Are you sure your data is correct?

Comment: I believe in your answer too. Yes I'm sure the data that given is correct. Instead of returning `Success` message in your else condition I changed it to `var_dump($users)` and it gives me output `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#172 (1) { ["EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?)"]=> int(0) } }`

Comment: Try using `$users[0]` and access the first (and only) element of the array, which should be a boolean from the query.

Comment: It still print me the same :(

Comment: Can you echo `$users[0]` to the console?  What is the value?

Comment: I tried to `echo "$users[0]"` and prints me nothing with success message. Can we move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115753/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-francisunoxx).

Answer (score 0):

The [Laravel 5.2 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries) says "The select method will always return an array of results." So you could use `count()` to see if there are any results in the array:

```
public function readEmployeeRecords()
{
    $users = DB::select('select * from users where username = ?', [1]);

    if ( ! count($users)) {
        return ('Failed');
    }

    return ('Success');
}
```

`is_null()` checks if a variable is `NULL`. An empty array is not equal to `NULL`

Comment: I think it's not finding the correct values in my database. I tried this but returns me a `Success` message.

Comment: @Francisunoxx Can you var_dump($users) and tell me what it prints ?

Comment: I put inside the `!count` method the `var_dump($users)` and gives me the output `array(0) { }` in any values that I select.

Comment: @Francisunoxx call it just before the if() statement

Comment: it prints me `array(0) { } Failed` does this mean it can't find the values in my database?

Comment: @Francisunoxx It seems that the select() method will return an empty array if no records match your query. Now try to get a record that you know exists and see what `$users` contains.

Comment: I'm sure this doesn't get the values in my database. I tried to select values but still return me `'False'`

Comment: @Francisunoxx reduce your query to `select * from users` and see what happens

Comment: @Francisunoxx Well, in this case the problem might be elsewhere. You  should check if you can connect to the database and if there are any records in the `users` table.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

if(is_null($users) || $users = "") {